# how to change class of a label for checkboxes in simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic, simple-form

using `simple_form` we can change class of a label using:

`label_html => {:class => "myclass"}`

but how do we do the same when dealing with checkboxes?

`simple_form` assigns the default class of `collection_check_boxes`

Is there a way to change this default class?

Comment: Works for me on version 2.0.2

Comment: Confirmed, this works for me, too.

Answer (score 65):

I wanted to give an update to this answer in case someone comes here looking for a way to do this as I did.

You can give the label a class with this option `:item_wrapper_class => 'class_goes_here'`

Here is a full example:

```
= user.input :resident, 
             :collection => [["In the U.S", true],["Outside the U.S.", false]], 
             :label_method => :first, 
             :value_method => :last,
             :as => :radio_buttons, 
             :label => "Where is your principle residence?",
             :item_wrapper_class => 'inline'
```

Comment: Thanks for this meng....really appreciate it. This has frustrated me, and you just saved my bacon. Much appreciated.

Comment: :item_wrapper_class adds a class, but how to remove current one ? simple_form adds class 'checkbox-inline'

Comment: label_html: {class: "some_class"} is one more option that can be useful

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer, @flynfish
There is also a method for separate item label:
`item_label_class: 'class-name'`

Comment: item_label_class: 'class-name' works for me. Is possible to configure this option in the initializer file?

Comment: thank you! ':item_wrapper_class' can be able to use for collection_check_boxes too.

Comment: `:item_wrapper_class` and `:item_label_class` is different. First one sets the outer class of the tag 'span' which encloses the label and checkbox in bootstrap. This was so helpful, I spent almost 2 hours trying to achieve inline checkboxes with simple_form

Answer (score 8):

If you want you can pass `new_class` to the label doing something like:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes attribute, collection, value_method, text_method do |b| 
      b.label(class: 'new_class') {b.check_box + b.text}
end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set :input_html on your form input.

Somthing like:

```
f.input :something, :as => :check_box, :input_html => { :class => "myclass" }
```

ian.

Comment: that takes effect on the `<input type=checkbox class="myclass">` not on `<label class="collection_check_boxes"><input type=checkbox....></label>`

Comment: `:label_html => { :class => "myclass" }` ended up working for me

Answer (score 2):

This should be pretty straight forward like mentioned above one should add `:label_html => { :class => "myclass" }` in order achieve this, for instance:

`= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean, :input_html => { :class => 'kt-checkbox kt-mock-span' }, :label_html => { :class => "kt-login-checkbox-label" }`

will create and assign the attributes for the styles on the checkbox's label like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to change the label class for a checkbox is to insert the following in **/config/inititializers/simple_form.rb** or **/config/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb**:

```
config.boolean_label_class = 'form-check-label'
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the label class I had to get rid of the auto-generated label and write my own.

this is in rails 3 with simple form 2.1 so YMMV....

before:

```
<%= f.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
```

after:

```
<%= f.label :remember_me, :class => 'remember-me' %>
<%= f.input :remember_me, :label => false, :as => :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
```