# Using simple_form how do I get this class on these inner labels vs the outer label ones?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

So this is the outcome I am trying to get:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="ListingType">Listing Type:</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <label class="inline"><input type="radio" name="ListingType"> For Sale</label>
    <label class="inline"><input type="radio" name="ListingType"> For Rent</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried this:

```
<%= f.association :listing_type, label: "Listing Type: ", as: :radio_buttons, input_html: { class: 'inline'} %>
```

This is what was produced:

```
<div class="control-group radio_buttons optional">
   <label class="radio_buttons optional control-label">Listing Type:</label>
   <div class="controls">
      <label class="radio"><input class="radio_buttons optional inline" id="listing_listing_type_id_1" name="listing[listing_type_id]" type="radio" value="1" />For Sale</label>
      <label class="radio"><input class="radio_buttons optional inline" id="listing_listing_type_id_2" name="listing[listing_type_id]" type="radio" value="2" />For Rent</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice the `label.class="radio"` as opposed to `label.class="inline"`.

That's the major thing I am trying to get done properly.

I tried `label_html: { class: 'inline' }` and it produces this:

```
<div class="control-group radio_buttons optional">
   <label class="radio_buttons optional control-label inline">Listing Type:</label>
   <div class="controls">
     <label class="radio"><input class="radio_buttons optional" id="listing_listing_type_id_1" name="listing[listing_type_id]" type="radio" value="1" />For Sale</label>
     <label class="radio"><input class="radio_buttons optional" id="listing_listing_type_id_2" name="listing[listing_type_id]" type="radio" value="2" />For Rent</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

i.e. it moves the class `inline` to the outermost `<label>` as opposed to the `label` for each radio button.

Thoughts?

Comment: Check this SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812325/how-to-change-class-of-a-label-for-checkboxes-in-simple-form

Comment: Perfect....you want to add the most upvoted answer there, i.e. the one with 6 upvotes, to this...and I will accept it. Just tried it and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just copying @flynfish answer from [how to change class of a label for checkboxes in simple_form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812325/how-to-change-class-of-a-label-for-checkboxes-in-simple-form) to this thread. Seems to be the one according to @marcamillion comment here.

> You can give the label a class with this option :item_wrapper_class =>
>   'class_goes_here'
>
> Here is a full example:
>
> ```
> = user.input :resident, 
>          :collection => [["In the U.S", true],["Outside the U.S.", false]], 
>          :label_method => :first, 
>          :value_method => :last,
>          :as => :radio_buttons, 
>          :label => "Where is your principle residence?",
>          :item_wrapper_class => 'inline'
> ```

Comment: This no longer works in the latest version, the class is applied to a span surrounding the label class :( - Wonder why they changed this :(

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @moonfly is no longer true for current version of `simple_form` (I have tried on version 3.3.1).

To change the class of each radio button label you have to use the option `item_label_class` like this:

```
<%= f.association :listing_type, label: "Listing Type: ", as: :radio_buttons, item_label_class: 'inline' %>
```

Or from @moonfly's answer:

```
= user.input :resident, 
     :collection => [["In the U.S", true],["Outside the U.S.", false]], 
     :label_method => :first, 
     :value_method => :last,
     :as => :radio_buttons, 
     :label => "Where is your principle residence?",
     :item_label_class => 'inline'
```

`item_wrapper_class` will modify the class of each radio button span for newer versions of simple_form.