# Inline checkboxes with simple_form association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I'd like to render each checkbox and label as a pair inline with the next checkbox-and-label pair on the next line.

I'm using simple_form's association method:

```
f.association :positions, as: :check_boxes
```

Is there a way to insert a tag - maybe a div - for each input-label pair? ...that can then be styled?

Answer (score 4):

Just to help other people that stumble over this:

simple_form's `associations` helper accepts `item_wrapper_tag` and `item_wrapper_class` options.

In your case, this could probably work:

`f.association :positions, as: :check_boxes, item_wrapper_tag: :div, item_wrapper_class: "style_item"`

sources:
http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/master/SimpleForm/FormBuilder:collection_check_boxes

[how to change class of a label for checkboxes in simple_form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812325/how-to-change-class-of-a-label-for-checkboxes-in-simple-form)