# setting a simple_form assocation item input or label class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have the following simple_form builder invocation:

```
f.association(:facility, { as: :radio_buttons, label: false })
```

Which generates:

```
<div class="attribute radio_buttons required swipe_facility">
  <ul>
    <input type="hidden" name="swipe[facility_id]" value="">
    <li class="radio">
      <input class="radio_buttons required" type="radio" value="10000" name="swipe[facility_id]" id="swipe_facility_id_10000">
      <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="swipe_facility_id_10000">Facility 1</label>
    </li>
    <li class="radio">
      <input class="radio_buttons required" type="radio" value="10001" name="swipe[facility_id]" id="swipe_facility_id_10001">
      <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="swipe_facility_id_10001">Facility 2</label>
    </li>
    <li class="radio">
      <input class="radio_buttons required" type="radio" value="10002" name="swipe[facility_id]" id="swipe_facility_id_10002">
      <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="swipe_facility_id_10002">Facility 3</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How do I add a class to these guys:

```
<label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="swipe_facility_id_10000">Facility 1</label>
```

The closest I've been able to get is adding a class to the LI tags with `item_wrapper_class`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change class of a label for checkboxes in simple\_form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812325/how-to-change-class-of-a-label-for-checkboxes-in-simple-form)

Comment: It's close. `input_html: { class: ... }` will add a class to the radios, but I haven't found a way to put a class on their labels yet.

Comment: What about the answer with `f.collection_check_boxes`? Try it with `collection_radio_buttons` helper

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you. I passed over it looking for a straight `.association` solution.